# Example bagfile of SICK LIDAR data on robot driving around

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, lidar, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in some example bagfile data of a robot driving around indoors with one of the large SICK scanners like the SICK LMS 200 (180 deg FOV, 1 deg angular resolution, high update rate of 75Hz). Does anyone know where to find such a bagfile? I don't have access to the hardware myself and seeing how many people have pioneers with SICK scanners on them, I'm sure there must be some bagfiles floating around somewhere :). I basically only need the scan data (provided the vehicle doesn't experience attitude changes/is driving on flat ground).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28846/example-bagfile-of-sick-lidar-data-on-robot-driving-around/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a [bagfile (5.8MB tar.bz2)](http://mobilerobots.case.edu/files/hallway_slow.bag.tar.bz2) that might work for you. On the `base_laser1_scan` topic you'll find the data from a SICK LMS291 outputting at 75Hz with 0.5 degree increments in a 180 degree FOV and 80 meters max range. The 0.5 degree increments actually means you get 2 separate 1 degree scans with slightly different angle_min and angle_max values to reflect the starting offset. If you just want 1 set of 1 degree scans, just pick a starting angle_min and filter all the scans with a different angle_min.

For a ground truth, these scans were taken while going from "X" to "O" and back on the map attached to this answer.

[image: Map of 2nd Floor of Glennan at CWRU]

The bagfile I linked also contains uncorrected odometry information for the robot (CWRU's HARLIE) as it moved along, as well as laser scan topics from a Hokuyo URG-04LX (or URG-04LX-UG01 I can't remember exactly which) and the laser extracted from a Neato XV-11.

If that bagfile doesn't contain what you were looking for, I can check this evening to see if I still have the bagfile that we built the posted map from with gmapping. I believe that one was taken with the scanner set to 1 degree resolution as opposed to 0.5 degree resolution.

UPDATE:

The bagfile that the map was built from (I'm ~90% certain) is [here (44MB tar.bz2)](http://mobilerobots.case.edu/files/2nd_floor_one_door_bringup_only_2010-10-02-22-11-50.bag.tar.bz2). I can't actually say for certain since my NVIDIA driver is currently in a weird state, so RViz isn't displaying laser data. The name and date are right for a data collection of that mapped area though.

The SICK was set to 1 degree mode, as there is only one angle_min value in the bagged data (`/base_laser1_scan` topic again). All other parameters were the same as above.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-03-01**:
Hi Eric, thanks for the bagfile, that already helps. A 1 deg resolution one would be even better, so if you find it let me know :) Thanks again.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-03-01**:
Updated my answer with the link to another bagfile. I'm certain that it has 1 deg resolution, and pretty positive that it could be used with gmapping to produce a map very similar to the one I posted (so it covers a much larger area than the bag I originally posted).

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-03-04**:
Thanks a lot for the additional data!